# Spring boot is not running with sql server using spring data and hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I'm trying to connect to MS SQL sever using Spring Boot spring data /jpa .
**I add the driver to my pom file**. I checked that spring data uses it ( when I change the name of it in the pom file delibratly  I get an error when running it, as I expected).

I use the following  params in application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.username=xxx

spring.datasource.password=yyy
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.jpa.database=sqlserver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

When running the application I get this:

`java.sql.SQLException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:280)`

my pom file looks like this:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
      <version>4.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

When I run a simple app using the same driver all is working..

Am I missing something? some parameters? Wrong parammeters?

Any idea?

Here is the complete stack trace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:280)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:200)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:699)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:633)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:484)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:142)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:115)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:102)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:522)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at com.ubs.Application.main(Application.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:359)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:268)
    ... 38 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace please.

Answer (score 7):

Are you sure about the `driverClassName`?

Shouldn't it be `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`?

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for! My configuration example was the same as above which is obviously wrong.